# How can I load only specific type of links in Android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a simple webview in my Android app. By default I have a local home page from `assets` folder which loads in the webview first. Inside the homepage, I have two type of links. When a user clicks the first type of link, it has to load inside the webview, whereas if the second type of link is clicked it has to be opened in the default browser.

I know I have to use the webview client, but am not sure how to do this link split up.

When I use the webview client, it loads all the URLs inside the webview. I wanted to load only few types of links inside the webview and other types of links into external default browser.

```
ex: <a href="http://www.example.com/" id="firstlinks" class="firstlinks">Load   My Webpage</a>  
ex: <a href="http://www.google.com/" id="secondlinks" class="secondlinks">Load Google.com</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set webview client https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: refer this question it has same implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979968/webview-loadurl-opens-the-url-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
  }
}
```